# Checkbox toggle square getting lost

Tags: html, css, styles, toggle

I have been working on a custom-styled checkbox, but for some reason, the square when the toggle is checked is getting lost.

Anyone could please point out what I did wrong with this checkbox?

https://jsfiddle.net/d67k5uyq/6/

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>switch toggle menu using html css only</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
      
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="default">
          <label for="default" data-checked="Checked" data-unchecked="Unchecked"></label>      
        </div>
        
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I believe is something to do with the before and after where I'm forgetting to set some value.

CSS

```
body{
  background: #485461;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  color: white; 
}

input[type=checkbox].toggle{
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox].toggle + label{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  font-size:20px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.3s ease; 
}

input[type=checkbox].toggle + label:before{
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  content: '';
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  z-index: 3;
}

input[type=checkbox].toggle + label:after{
  width: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

input[type=checkbox].toggle:not(:checked) + label{
 background-color: transparent;
 text-align: right;
}

input[type=checkbox].toggle:not(:checked) + label:after{
  content: attr(data-unchecked);
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  color: white;
}

input[type=checkbox].toggle:not(:checked) + label:before{
   left: 4px;
   background-color: white;
}

input[type=checkbox].toggle:checked + label{
   text-align: left;
   border-color: yellow;
}

input[type=checkbox].toggle:checked + label:after{
   content: attr(data-checked);
   left: 4px;
   right: auto;
   opacity: 1;
   color: white;
}

input[type=checkbox].toggle:checked + label:before{
   left: 144px;
   border-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the input is unchecked then the before pseudo element is given a background color of white.

When it is checked then it is given a color to the border, but the border has not been given any width.

Assuming you want a yellow bordered square the this snippet not only sets the border color but also solid and 1px width.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>switch toggle menu using html css only</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background: #485461;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .container {
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 30px;
      color: white;
    }
    
    input[type=checkbox].toggle {
      display: none;
    }
    
    input[type=checkbox].toggle+label {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 60px;
      width: 200px;
      position: relative;
      font-size: 20px;
      border: 4px solid white;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
    
    input[type=checkbox].toggle+label::before {
      position: absolute;
      top: 4px;
      height: 44px;
      width: 44px;
      content: '';
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
      z-index: 3;
    }
    
    input[type=checkbox].toggle+label::after {
      width: 140px;
      text-align: center;
      z-index: 2;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
      content: 'A';
    }
    
    input[type=checkbox].toggle:not(:checked)+label {
      background-color: transparent;
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    input[type=checkbox].toggle:not(:checked)+label::after {
      content: attr(data-unchecked);
      right: 0;
      left: auto;
      opacity: 1;
      color: white;
    }
    
    input[type=checkbox].toggle:not(:checked)+label::before {
      left: 4px;
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    input[type=checkbox].toggle:checked+label {
      text-align: left;
      border-color: yellow;
    }
    
    input[type=checkbox].toggle:checked+label::after {
      content: attr(data-checked);
      left: 4px;
      right: auto;
      opacity: 0.5;
      color: white;
    }
    
    input[type=checkbox].toggle:checked+label::before {
      left: 144px;
      border-color: yellow;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="default">
      <label for="default" data-checked="Checked" data-unchecked="Unchecked"></label>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```